# Ciclo por conteo for solo imprime la operación de la última vuelta y debería en teoría imprimir uno por cada vuelta

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, bucles, dom

En este código tengo una confusión pues veo que el ciclo por conteo for solo imprime la operación de la última vuelta y debería en teoría imprimir uno por cada vuelta del mismo, pero no encuentro el por qué pisa los datos de las vueltas anteriores. Quizás es que lo he planteado de una manera incorrecta.

```
let numberGuest = Number(prompt("Ingrese el numero de personas huespedes"))
let costoMax = Number(prompt("Ingrese el limite de precio de la habitacion"))
let service = confirm("Deseas incluir el paquete all inclusive")

const rooms=[
    {nombre: "Clasica", precio: 1500, espacio: 2, allInclusive: true},
    {nombre: "Clasica", precio: 1000, espacio: 2, allInclusive: false},
    {nombre: "Triple", precio: 2000, espacio: 3, allInclusive: true},
    {nombre: "Triple", precio: 2500, espacio: 3, allInclusive: false},
    {nombre: "Suit", precio: 3500, espacio: 4, allInclusive: false},
    {nombre: "Suit", precio: 4500, espacio: 4, allInclusive: true},
    {nombre: "Suit Presidencial", precio: 5500, espacio: 5, allInclusive: false},
    {nombre: "Suit Presidencial", precio: 6000, espacio: 5, allInclusive: true},
]

let result= rooms
    result= numberGuest ? rooms.filter(room => room.espacio>=numberGuest) : result
    result= costoMax ? result.filter(room => room.precio<=costoMax) : result
    result= result.filter(room => room.allInclusive===service)

console.log (result)

const imprimir = document.getElementById('contenedor')

for(let i=0; i< result.length; i+=1 ){
    imprimir.innerHTML=`
    <div class="card">
                    <img src="" alt="">
                    <div class="info">
                        <p class="Habitacion"><strong>Habitacion:</strong> ${result[i].nombre}</p>
                        <p class="Precio"><strong>Precio:</strong> ${result[i].precio}</p>
                        <p class="Espacio"><strong>Espacio:</strong> ${result[i].espacio}</p>
                        <p class="AllInclusive"><strong>Todo incluido:</strong> ${result[i].allInclusive}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>`
}






<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <div id="contenedor">
            

        </div>
    </main>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pon imprimir.innerhtml += porque con = solamente estas sobreimprimiendo los resultados

Comment: Donde comienza `let result= rooms`, inicia el filter y siempre arroja como `length = 1` por todos los filtros que le pasas y si no encuentra nada, solo arroja `length = 0`, en cualquier caso el `for` solo se repetirá una vez o ninguna; así pues ejecuta solo una vez (o ninguna) el `innerHTML`.